# HTML parsing with Simple DOM Parser for PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

```
<div class="listing-new type-standard">
        <a href="/someLink" class="link-block cfix"data-eventaction="ListingOpened">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <p>testing</p>
            </div>
        </a>
 </div>
```

I tried to parse the code above using both in-built dom functions and the simple_html_dom_parser. Unfortunately, I could not succeed in with Simple Html Dom Parser. It doesn't find anything.

*SimpleHtmlDomParser way*

```
foreach($html->find('a[data-eventaction]') as $element){
        echo $element->href . "\r\n";
}
```

*Normal DOM way which worked*

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);  
$list = $xpath->query("//a[@data-eventaction=ListingOpened]");
```

I believe the reason simple parser doesn't work is the attribute "data-eventaction" doesn't have a space before it. Because, If I add space, it also works.

Any quick solutions?

Comment: `cfix"data-...` is illegal html... attribute names cannot contain `"`

Comment: if you add a space before `data-eventaction` it works ? Seems strange according to @MarcB comment...

Comment: then it becomes `<a .... cfix" data-eventaction=...`. `cfix"` will be an illegal attribute, and data-eventaction becomes a normal attribute. you're just luck that your browser chose to ignore that extra `"` and didn't somehow transform it into `cfix="data-eventaction="`

Comment: @MarcB where is there an extra `"` ? the `<a>` has 2 classes : `link-block` and `cfix`...

Comment: You can switch to [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) and it will work. How's that for a quick solution?

Comment: @pguardiario yes man.. It works so far.. Brilliant job.. thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @pguardiario How do add this library to Laravel man? Composer.json doesn't have an autoload section and I could not find a way fix it. :(

Comment: @bavan, you should just need to switch out simple for advanced in your includes.